# Compile time errors for generated code?

Tags: types, clojure, f#, functional-programming, metaprogramming

Is there a type system that expands macros and gives you type errors on the generated code that will eventually be executed?

A practical example might be generating some SQL dynamically but receiving syntax errors from the compiler based on some constraints (before executing the code).

Another example could be generating a function with n nested for loops to generate n combinations.

Often generating source code is frowned upon because it will be "stringly typed", so I'm wondering if there is a type system that can use constraints to give you valuable feedback while write code that generates code.

Comment: I'm not sure it is what you want, but have you looked at F# type providers?

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in talking to SQL.   I'm interested in getting compiler feedback when writing code that generates code.

Comment: An example might be writing a transpiler to javascript, you'll be generating JS, and it'd be nice to get compiler feedback in your given language if your function is going to generate invalid code upon execution.

Comment: I suspect that you are looking for a "compiler as a service". That's exactly what the Roslyn compilers for C# and VB.NET are. F# doesn't use Roslyn but a compiler service is available through the [F# Compiler Service](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/) package

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to what you outline that comes to mind is [typed tagless final approach](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/tagless-typed.html). While it is not strictly speaking a macro feature, but it behaves very similar to macro expansion (and I would argue better in many respects.) What makes it relevant to you is the expressions targeted for expansion/transformation are strongly typed *by construction* - target expression types are directly presented as metalanguage types and checked by the compiler.

This approach assumes you have an expressive enough type system in the metalanguage that covers the types of your target language. As [has been demonstrated](http://okmij.org/ftp/meta-programming/quel.pdf) you can cover a large subset of SQL this way (actually nested relational calculus, it translates to SQL directly, and as with all applications of final tagless approach, strongly typed by construction.)

If you check the references above you will find plenty of examples in ML so you should have no trouble using F# for this purpose.